# I am trying to create a circular LinkedList Please tell me if its a correct way to do it

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

i have implemented logic like if i am giving a index that is not yet there then it will change the index to the reminder (Same like rotated i guess ).

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MycircularlinkedList extends LinkedList {

    private static int count = 0;

    public Object get(int i) {
        System.out.println("count==" + count);
        if (i > count) {
            i = i % count;
            return super.get(i);

        } else {
            return super.get(i);
        }

    }

    public boolean add(Object o) {

        super.add(o);
        count++;
        return true;
    }

    public void add(int i, Object o) {
        if (i > count)
            i = i % count;
        super.add(i, o);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need count, you can use size()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.

(1) The term "[circular linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list)" is well-known to mean a list where the tail links back to the head (and vice versa if it's a doubly-linked list). Yours is more like a "circular buffer" stored in a linked list. We could call it `LinkedListCircularBuffer` or something.

(2) The class should be parameterized by the element type, thus

```
public class LinkedListCircularBuffer<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
  @Override
  public E get(int i) {
    return super.get(i % size()); // simpler and faster without an "if"
  }
}
```

(3) You can call `size()` instead of all the code to maintain another `count`.

(4) Your `add(int i, Object o)` method doesn't support the case where `i == size()`, but you can fix that by not overriding `add()` at all.

(5) Overridden methods need the `@Override` annotation.

(6) It's good style to *always* put braces around each "then" and "else" clause. Code like

```
if (i > count)
  i = i % count;
```

is fragile, e.g. adding a `println()` statement into that "then" clause will break it.

Comment: I thought of using size earlier but i dont know why i didn't used it.

Thanks for your help guys i will try what you have suggested here.

Comment: I have tried the above suggestions and obviously its working as it should be.
But can anyone tell me any other way (more professional) way of doing it.?

Comment: The code above is fine if this design fits your use. If you instead want a fixed size circular buffer, search the web for "Java circular buffer".

Comment: There are plenty more collection classes available in the Java correction library, also in Google's Guava library and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points I can see:

1. `count` is static, this means you're only ever going to have one number here. Probably not what you want
2. `count` is redundant, use `Collection#size()`
3. The great thing about mod (`%`) is that it works for all numbers, you don't need to have the conditional. `2 % 12 == 14 % 12 == -10 % 12`
4. If you're getting rid of the `count` property, you can get rid of your overridden `#add(Object o)` logic and just do `return super.add(o);`

Answer (score 1):

I find some problem with your code: if count ==0 and if I use the method add(7,obj) ,then 7%0 will throw ArithmeticException.count should be declared to private since you may have two instances of your class.Also,you need to check 
whether poll\offerLast method satisfies your needs,since you cant restrict 
any client code to avoid using them.Finally,clone\readObject\writeObject 
need to be overrried to include the count variable.

Comment: Luchy you are right i also can see that. and that was anyway resolved i wanted to show my logic that is it a good way to implement a circular linked list..thanks for pointing out my mistakes i hope in future also you will be a great help for me.

Comment: I think you can implement your own circularlinkedlist ,because it  has no first or last  node,but  a  linkedlist  has them.So in this case ,using  inheritance is not a good practice.